# Getting "Umbraco is not configured" while upgrading to 6.2.6 and struck at 90%

Tags: .net, content-management-system, umbraco, upgrade, umbraco6

Getting "Umbraco is not configured" error repeatedly in UmbracoLog while upgrading to 6.2.6.

Databse upgrade is struck at 90% and never get through.

```
2018-03-09 10:47:45,983 [76] INFO  Umbraco.Core.ApplicationContext - [Thread 73] CurrentVersion different from configStatus: '6.2.6','6.1.6'
2018-03-09 10:47:45,983 [76] WARN  Umbraco.Web.UmbracoModule - [Thread 73] Umbraco is not configured
```

Any idea what could be the reason?

I have checked permissions and database connection. Both are fine.

Thanks, Tom

Answer (score 0):

This error is thrown whenever the Umbraco version in your umbraco.dll (inside the bin folder) is different from the version at `umbracoConfigurationStatus` setting in your web.config. 
Can you make sure they are the same?

If not you should correct the version in `umbracoConfigurationStatus` with the one in umbraco.dll and/or revert your files to a point before you ran the upgrade.